# How to create a state for two buttons android

Tags: java, android

I have two Buttons, Male and Female, and what I want to do is, if the user select a Male button, change the background color, the way that it works as a RadioGroup, just can select Male or Female.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_male"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/male"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="genderPerson"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_female"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="@string/female"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="genderPerson"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "the way that it works as a RadioGroup" so use RadioGroup

Answer (score 1):

Usually for these kind of requirements i suggest you to use `RadioButton` instead of `Buttons`

you can achieve easily like below

```
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pirates"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ninjas"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
 </RadioGroup>
```

and in Activity

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
// Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio_pirates:
        if (checked)
            // Pirates are the best
        break;
    case R.id.radio_ninjas:
        if (checked)
            // Ninjas rule
        break;
}
}
```

for more info refer here
[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)

this complete example [example](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing but for other thing, but the design has to be like this, with two buttons, I was trying to create some logic to get the click of one and disable the other, but it doesn't work!

Comment: you can change background of `RadioButton` to look like `Button`